# jQueryUI Autocomplete: Trigger on textbox focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to get a jQuery autocomplete instance to open on the textbox focus, and fetch data from the remote source. An approximation of my attempt is shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ug2aG/1/

The problem with this is that you'll note the extra call to the textbox focus method when you select a value from the dropdown. I can't figure out a way to prevent this extra call, as it is interfering with the functionality.

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't see the problem in FF8 or Chrome

Comment: do you mean if the textbox get focused multiple time, "Getting values" text appeared multiple times?

Comment: @Hery Yes, that's right. The 'getting values' shouldn't trigger multiple times

Comment: @PerpetuallyInquisitive: Ah, I see. That is weird!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution that's not too hacky:

```
$('#tags').focus(function() {
    /* Only search if the autocomplete menu is hidden: */
    if ($("ul.ui-autocomplete").is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).autocomplete('search', '');
    }
});
```

**Updated example:** http://jsfiddle.net/9x3hu/

If you're curious, [here's the line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L242) that's causing you grief. Looks like after you select an item, the `input` targeted by the widget is focused automatically.

This might seem odd, but it probably has to do with using the `UP` and `DOWN` arrows to navigate the dropdown list. In that case, you'd want focus to return to the `input`.

Answer (score 0):

is that because you use append..

try this:

```
$('#status').html('<br />getting values...');
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't state that properly - the problem isn't that 'getting values' is displaying twice. The problem is that the source method of the autocomplete is being invoked twice. The message is just there to help track this. Edit: In other words, try clicking on the textbox and selecting a value from the dropdown - the focus method will be triggered again.

Comment: don't see the problem in chromre and ie9.

Comment: what browser do you use to test?

Comment: I've tested in Chrome, FF, IE. Aren't you able to reproduce it? 1. Click on textbox (shows 'getting values'). 2. Click on one of the values (shows 'getting values' again).

Comment: i think the reason because you attach onfocus event to the textbox. when you select the value, autocomplete library will set the value to textbox and set the focus to it.